# Grouping the same object according to the elements of their lists

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have following list of the objects of type `Application`, which looks like:

```
public class Application
    {
        public int AppId { get; set; }
        public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    }
```

What I want to do is to map them to object of type `Section` looking like:

```
public class Section
       {
            public List<int> AppIds { get; set; }
            public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        }
```

by grouping them according to following rule: gather all the same questions under the lists of AppIds, which contain these questions. Exemplary Input and Output:

```
Input: A1(Q1,Q2,Q3), A2(Q1,Q2), A3(Q1,Q3), A4(Q1). 
Output: A1,A2,A3,A4(Q1), A1,A2(Q2), A1,A3(Q3)
```

Is that possible to do it in LINQ? Or I have to write logic on my own?

Comment: What have you tried already?  What _specifically_ is not working?

Comment: I just dont have specific idea from where to start

Comment: What is the expected outcome for `A1(Q1, Q2)`, `A2(Q2, Q3)`, `A3(Q1, Q3)`?

Comment: @Pawel normally you need to show _some_ attempt here.  If you absolutely zero idea how to start then you at least need to give us a sample input & output.  We dont have a very clear desired functionality here.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, it will be: A1,A3(Q1), A1,A2(Q2), A2,A3(Q3)

Comment: @maccettura, sorry, I added it now

Comment: Might just be me, but I don't think the logic is right.. how can we/you group by the same questions based on the `AppId`?  All applications should have a different `AppId`, so there is nothing to group by that?  I think we should be grouping by questions.. since some applications contain the same questions.. hence grouping

Comment: Yes, of course I meant grouping by questions, as it is shown in exemplary input and output. I described it maybe not t very clearly so I will correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a simpler way, but this is the first `LINQ` query I wrote and should be enough to at least get you started. First I flattened out your questions and appids, then I regrouped by questions and listed your appids by question instead. Note that you'll have to populate your `List` of applications before this will run.

```
List<Application> app = new List<Application>();
var output = (from a in app.SelectMany(p => p.Questions.Select(z => new {z, p.AppId})
group a.AppId by new 
{
a.Questions
} into combined
select new 
{
combined.Key.Questions,
combined.ToList()
});
```

Comment: So basically you did not achieved what I wanted, but I decided to change the structure of Section class to have only one question - and in this way it does its job( however i will apply small changes to your code, because it did not compiled, and also add Section class). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the question was portrayed a little off.  Each application *should* have a different `AppId`, so essentially there is nothing to group by because all `AppId`s are different.  Instead, we should be grouping by the questions, since each application could potentially have the same question.

Here is what I have (it doesn't match the exact output, in terms of styling, because your sample output is based on grouping by the `AppId` and not the question, but the expected results are the same):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        // create Questions

        var questionOne = new Question(){QuestionId = 1, ActualQuestion = "Who"};
        var questionTwo = new Question(){QuestionId = 2, ActualQuestion = "What"};
        var questionThree = new Question(){QuestionId = 3, ActualQuestion = "Where"};

        // Assign questions to the specified list of questions

        var applicationOneQuestions = new List<Question>(){questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree};
        var applicationTwoQuestions = new List<Question>() {questionOne, questionTwo};
        var applicationThreeQuestions = new List<Question>() {questionOne, questionThree};
        var applicationFourQuestions = new List<Question>() {questionOne};

        // Create Applications

        var applicationOne = new Application(){AppId = 1, Questions = applicationOneQuestions};
        var applicationTwo = new Application(){AppId = 2, Questions = applicationTwoQuestions};
        var applicationThree = new Application() {AppId = 3, Questions = applicationThreeQuestions};
        var applicationFour = new Application() {AppId = 4, Questions = applicationFourQuestions};

        // Create List of Applications

        var lstApplications = new List<Application>(){applicationOne, applicationTwo, applicationThree, applicationFour};

        // Group Applications based on Questions and cast to Section Object

        var groupApplications = lstApplications.GroupBy(x => x.Questions).Select(t => new Section { AppIds = t.Select(z => z.AppId).ToList() , Questions = t.Key}).ToList();

        foreach(var item in groupApplications)
        {
            foreach(var appId in item.AppIds)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(appId);

            }

            foreach(var question in item.Questions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(question.ActualQuestion);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
}

public class Application
    {
        public int AppId { get; set; }
        public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    }

public class Section
       {
            public List<int> AppIds { get; set; }
            public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        }

public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId {get;set;}
    public string ActualQuestion {get;set;} 
}
```

**Output**

```
// 1
// Who
// What
// Where

// 2
// Who
// What

// 3
// Who
// Where

// 4
// Who
```

---

- Application 1, 2, 3, 4 all contain question one
- Application 1, 2 contain question two
- Application 1, 3 contain question three

---

Please let me know if this helps.  I have created a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PAcgWg) for you as well to test on your own and give me feedback.

Comment: Okay, but now basically output is the same what input. What I want to achieve is to have Output as you wrote: 
`Application 1, 2, 3, 4 all contain question one
Application 1, 2 contain question two
Application 1, 3 contain question three`. In other words: `//1,2,3,4 Who //1,2 What //1,3 Where`