# Change style of output with LINQ, GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PAcgWg).

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {       
        // create Questions

        var questionOne = new Question(){QuestionId = 1, ActualQuestion = "Who"};
        var questionTwo = new Question(){QuestionId = 2, ActualQuestion = "What"};
        var questionThree = new Question(){QuestionId = 3, ActualQuestion = "Where"};

        // Assign questions to the specified list of questions

        var applicationOneQuestions = new List<Question>(){questionOne, questionTwo, questionThree};
        var applicationTwoQuestions = new List<Question>() {questionOne, questionTwo};
        var applicationThreeQuestions = new List<Question>() {questionOne, questionThree};
        var applicationFourQuestions = new List<Question>() {questionOne};

        // Create Applications

        var applicationOne = new Application(){AppId = 1, Questions = applicationOneQuestions};
        var applicationTwo = new Application(){AppId = 2, Questions = applicationTwoQuestions};
        var applicationThree = new Application() {AppId = 3, Questions = applicationThreeQuestions};
        var applicationFour = new Application() {AppId = 4, Questions = applicationFourQuestions};

        // Create List of Applications

        var lstApplications = new List<Application>(){applicationOne, applicationTwo, applicationThree, applicationFour};

        // Group Applications based on Questions

        var groupApplications = lstApplications.GroupBy(x => x.Questions).Select(t => new Section { AppIds = t.Select(z => z.AppId).ToList() , Questions = t.Key}).ToList();

        foreach(var item in groupApplications)
        {
            foreach(var appId in item.AppIds)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(appId);

            }

            foreach(var question in item.Questions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(question.ActualQuestion);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
    }
}

public class Application
    {
        public int AppId { get; set; }
        public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    }

public class Section
       {
            public List<int> AppIds { get; set; }
            public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        }

public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId {get;set;}
    public string ActualQuestion {get;set;} 
}
```

Once you run the program, you get an output like so:

```
1
Who
What
Where


2
Who
What


3
Who
Where


4
Who
```

Now, I would like to change the output to look like this:

```
A1, A2, A3, A4 - Who
A1, A2 - What
A1, A3 - Where
```

Basically,

- application 1,2,3,4 all contain question 1 - who
- application 1, 2 contain question 2 - what
- application 1, 3 contain question 3 - where

How do I achieve this output?

Comment: Are you asking us to answer here the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860661/grouping-the-same-object-according-to-the-elements-of-their-lists) you were trying to answer with the above code?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, I'm currently trying to figure out how to adjust the groupby and select, but having trouble.. if you want to answer on that question that's fine.. at this point I'm curious

Comment: I think the whole problem is stated wrongly. First `lstApplications.GroupBy(x => x.Questions)` does nothing useful - the lists are compared by reference, hence the result is basically the same list as the input. Second the `Section` class is strange - it should contain single `Question`, not list. Which at the end leads to how to transform  `List<(Application, List<Questions>)>` to `List<(Question, List<Application>)>` which is trivial - `SelectMany` + `GroupBy`

Comment: I added an answer to the other one that I think gives the desired output (untested so take it with a grain of salt). It's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860661/grouping-the-same-object-according-to-the-elements-of-their-lists/51863064#51863064)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the method syntax would be, but here's a query syntax that will get you the desired output. I think the trouble you're having in trying to get the method syntax down is likely due to using a `Select` where you'd want to use a `SelectMany`.

```
var questionGroups = from application in lstApplications
                     from question in application.Questions
                     group application.AppId by question.ActualQuestion;


foreach (var question in questionGroups)
    Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(" ", question.Select(x => $"A{x}"))} - {question.Key}");
```

Comment: Sorry, can you write this out in lambda form?

Comment: @M12Bennett I think it's `lstApplications.SelectMany(x => application.Questions, (x, y) => new { x, y });`

Answer (score 0):

With query syntax:

```
var appGroups =
  from app in lstApplications
  from question in app.Questions
  group app by question;
```

With lambda syntax:

```
var appGroups = lstApplications
    .SelectMany(app => app.Questions, (app, question) => new { app, question })
    .GroupBy(item => item.question, item => item.app);
```

Printing the output:

```
foreach (var appGroup in appGroups)
    Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(", ", appGroup.Select(app => "A" + app.AppId))} - {appGroup.Key.ActualQuestion}");
```